# "Undefined variable: _SESSION" VS. "A session had already been started"

Tags: php, session, error-reporting

Hey.
I have some php scripts. In one of them i have the code session_start(), and when I in another script again have session_start() i get the notice:

> Notice: A session had already been started...

Thats logical. But when I remove it I get the error/notice:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION

Why? And how do I fix it? The scripts works fine when I have session_start() two places in the script (only get an little notice), but doesn't work at all when I doesn't have two session_start().

Is the only solution to have an

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

in my script? And isn't that bad practice to just ignore notices?

**Edit:**

Parts of my code:

```
            try {
            //session_start();

            $STH = DB::prepare  (   "UPDATE users SET DJ_name=?, DJ_showname=? WHERE id=?" );
            $STH->execute(array($_POST['DJ_name'], $_POST['DJ_showname'], $_SESSION['userid']));

            pre_dump($_SESSION);

            $_SESSION['DJ_name']        =   $_POST['DJ_name'];
            $_SESSION['DJ_showname']    =   $_POST['DJ_showname'];
        }
```

Output:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in D:.....\main.php on line 19
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in D:.....\main.php on line 21
>
> NULL

pre_dump code:

```
    function pre_dump($var)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($var);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Sounds weird. What about `$GLOBALS['_SESSION']`?

Comment: Why aren't you keeping just 1 session_start ?

Comment: Are you using PHP < 4.1?

Comment: $GLOBALS['_SESSION'] isn't working

Comment: HoLyVieR: I didn't know that I had another session_start. But when I got the notice I removed it, and then was it that the other strange error came.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the error myself.
Had an session_start() somewhere in my script that I didn't notice. Everything seems working now.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like `unset($_SESSION);` was called.

Comment: Right, this would trigger both warnings: `session_start(); unset($_SESSION); session_start(); echo $_SESSION;`. I do not know of any other way that would happen, other than an (unlikely) PHP bug.

Comment: Could it be this?

     session_write_close();

Comment: Didn't worked. Tried removing session_write_close();. The only thing happening was that I got 5 more notices that session had already been started.

Comment: I tried recreating my situation with session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION); and session_write_close(); in some new php files.

But wasn't able to recreate the error/notice. Concluding it's an error in my script, not in PHP itself.

Comment: if you remove `session_write_close`, you shouldn't need to call `session_start` again. You'll just have to remember to close the session after you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem recently. I could not access the contents of the $_SESSION variable.

1) This was as a result of trying to access the $_SESSION variable before the declaration of `session_start();` In my own case, I had already started a session in a header.php file. But I was accessing the $_SESSION variable before the include statement. Example;

```
<?php
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];
 //do some logical operation!!!
?> 
<?php include("header.php");?>
```

instead of doing something like this

```
<?php include("header.php");?>
<?php
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];
 //do some logical operation!!!
?>
```

2) Another thing that may cause this problem, maybe a failure to start a session at the top of all the files that may require access to the $_SESSION variable using

```
session_start();
```

Hope this helps anybody that stumbles on the same problem. Although this is coming at a late hour.

Answer (score -1):

$_SESSION always exists no matter whether you run session_start() or not. So I think something else must be causing your error.

Could you post the code? It could be you have unset the variable somewhere (see [this link](http://fr.php.net/session_unset)).

Comment: It does not exist if `session_start()` has not been called (PHP 5.3.3).